# Edit both opening and closing html tag brackets

Tags: windows-10, plugins, extension, brackets

Is there a way, either through core or plugin, when changing an HTML opening tag, to also change the closing one? For example: If i have the following code:

```
<div>Some Text</div>
```

So right now, if I want to switch from a `div` to a `span`, I would have to change the opening **and** closing tag to `span`. What I'm asking is, if there's a plugin or something, that all you have to change is 1 `tag`, then it will automatically change the other `tag`?

Comment: What program are you using to write your HTML? What operating system?

Comment: I'm using Brackets in Windows 10

Comment: It should do that. Try to see on your **Edit** menu, any "Auto close..." option checked?

Comment: It does auto close, but I want it to auto change

Comment: Emmet, the most widely used plugin for Brackets doesn't do that so i am not sure if there is anything else that would do it either

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do this with a very easy trick.

1. select opening tag
2. press ctrl button and then select closing tag.

Now you are ready to change it both at the same time.

Comment: Using which program?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).